# Get firstname and lastname contact page Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail, contact-us, contact-form

I want to get the first and last name in a custom contact form in Magento 1.9.x

in my custom_contact.phtml  file I have this:

```
<?php


if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    // Get the customer object from customer session
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

    $custID = $customer->getID();//get customer id
    $custFirstName = $customer->getFirstname();
    $custLastName = $customer->getLastname();
    $custEmail = $customer->getEmail();//get customer email
}

?>

   <div class="field">
                    <label for="xfirstname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('First Name') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="xcustom" id="xcustom" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
                        <input name="xfirstname" id="xfirstname" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('First Name') ?>" value="<?php echo $custFirstName ?>" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="xlastname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Last Name') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input name="xlastname" id="xlastname" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Last Name') ?>" value="<?php echo $custLastName ?>" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and I add this conditions in the transactional email:

```
{{if xcustom}}First Name: {{var customer.xfirstname}}{{else}}{{/if}}
{{if xcustom}}First Name: {{var customer.xlastname}}{{else}}{{/if}}

Name: {{var data.name}}
Email: {{var data.email}}
Telephone: {{var data.telephone}}



Comment: {{var data.comment}}
```

but Firsname and Lastname content not exist in my email. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code

```
{{if data.xfirstname}}First Name: {{var data.xfirstname}}{{else}}{{/if}}
{{if data.xlastname}}First Name: {{var data.xlastname}}{{else}}{{/if}}
```

Comment: thank you, I checked and is the same no data for xfirstname and xlastname

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: I see but is there any way to have only one if statement?

Comment: What you want to display?

Comment: I have two contacts forms, I search for a solution to change the email template for each form and I find only this solution

Comment: But your question is different. As per your question you want to display firstname and lastname in your email template.

Comment: you ask me what I want to display and I answer you

Comment: and my question is we can add a hidden field there as I do that xcustom and then to check if that exist?

Comment: I am asking about - I see but is there any way to have only one if statement?

Comment: yes, the custom contact form will be completely different